# Still having error in "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." in CodeIgniter Login with Facebook

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, uri

*I've searched all posts and I find this same error they encountered. Most comments and feedback was successfully fixed, but when I do mine, it really doesn't work :/ Help me out please:(*

I've already changed the `system/application/config/config.php` file from:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

to

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\-';
```

and

in this folder `system/libraries/URI.php` file from:

```
if ( ! preg_match("|^[".str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-'))."]+$|i", $str))
```

to

```
if ( ! preg_match("|^[".($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'))."]+$|i", rawurlencode($str)))
```

Still the  "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." exists.

Comment: How exactly is this connected to tag “facebook”?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I have for my facebook enabled app

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '+=a-z 0-9?~%.,:_\-';
```

I've seen people who've had success also enabling the below, but mine is still set to FALSE

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Hi, @WingLian , I tried it but this is what happened: 'The page you requested was not found.'

Comment: Do you get the page requested not found error when enable_query_strings is set to false? Also can you paste the query string that is causing the error?

Comment: No. It doesn't show up anything. Just the "404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found."

Comment: I return it back to FALSE boolean and “The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.” appeared again. Is there any problem in my php version or codeigniter? I am using a 1.7.2 version of codeigniter and my PHP Version is 5.3.1

Comment: Sorry to be repetitive, but can you provide the query string that is causing the error?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I can't find it actually. It never run before. I download this example from Git --> https://github.com/ncerminara/Facebook-Starter-Kit-for-Codeigniter/blob/master/README . It's from Nic. I'm only running this in my localhost. You can try it, and figure out the error. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue today when we upgraded to PHP 5.3, it turns out the solution was to update this line from `_filter_uri()` in `URI.php`

```
if ( ! preg_match("|^[".preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'))."]+$|i", $str))
```

With this new line from the [CodeIgniter repository version](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/URI.php):

```
if ( ! preg_match('|^['.str_replace(array('\\-', '\-'), '-', preg_quote($this->config->item('permitted_uri_chars'), '-')).']+$|i', $str))
```